# How to edit the NEW modal dialog?

Tags: lightning-experience, account, ui, lightning-recordeditform

On Services. When I got to the Account tab there is a "NEW" button. Hitting this button will pop up a modal with a couple of fields. How do I edit this modal? I would like to add an iframe to it.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the iframe?

Comment: Communicate with the server and display real time data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to add content other than sObject fields to the New modal is to override the New action on the relevant sObject. This would require you to write a Lightning component or Visualforce page, which must provide *all* of the required functionality to create a new object - including obtaining and rendering the relevant page layout.

Because the barrier to entry here is fairly high, I typically advise to consider carefully before doing so. Overriding the New action imposes maintenance costs on you (having to keep up with changes to page layouts, for example, if you do not use the UI API to render them), and is overall a heavy solution that always requires code. If there's other ways to achieve what you need to do, they often will come at a lower cost.

Comment: Thanks David, I was afraid this was going to be the answer. I was trying another way around creating new component.